# jquery target group of <p> elements between a set of <h4> elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<h4>Option 1</h4>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
<p>Baz</p>

<h2>Option 2</h4>
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p>
<p>ghi</p>

...

<h4>Option 1000</h4>
<p>123</p>
<p>456</p>
<p>789</p>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is adding a `.active` class on all of the `<p>` tags below a `<h4>` when the heading is clicked.

Using jquery (3.2.1) I am targeting the `<h4>` and determining whether it has been clicked:

```
$('h4').click(function (e) {

});
```

My intention is to only target the `<p>` tags below the clicked `<h4>` whilst ignoring any others. I can't see how to do this in jquery, so have resorted to adding classes to each series of options, e.g.

```
<h4 class="option1">Option 1</h4>
<p class="option1">Foo</p>
<p class="option1">Bar</p>
<p class="option1">Baz</p>
```

I can then read the class name. For example this gives "option1":

```
$('h4').click(function() {
   var clickedClass = $(this).attr("class");
   console.log(clickedClass); 
});
```

Using `clickedClass` I can then target the relevant elements and apply another class, in this case `.active`:

```
$(clickedClass).addClass('active');
```

Although this works it seems to be bloating my markup because I'm adding a lot of classes just to do this.

Is there an easier method using the set of markup given at the beginning of the question (without the class names) where you can target the child `<p>` tags in this way?

The intention is that if you clicked "Option 1" it would *only* apply `.active` to the clicked element and the child `<p>` elements, so the resultant markup should be this:

```
<h4 class="active">Option 1</h4>
<p class="active">Foo</p>
<p class="active">Bar</p>
<p class="active">Baz</p>

<h2>Option 2</h4>
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p>
<p>ghi</p>

...

<h4>Option 1000</h4>
<p>123</p>
<p>456</p>
<p>789</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need to use is [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil). It will select all the elements between the current and the sibling which matches the selector provided.

```js
$('h4').click(function(e) {
  $(this).nextUntil('h4').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Option 1</h4>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
<p>Baz</p>

<h4>Option 2</h4>
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p>
<p>ghi</p>

<h4>Option 1000</h4>
<p>123</p>
<p>456</p>
<p>789</p>
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks Rory. I wasn't aware of `nextUntil()`

Comment: Although this is the simplest solution - given you can change the markup - I would change the  `<h4>... <p>... <p>... <p>...` to be children of a `<section>` - tag. You seem to have different themes or another logically devided content that should be reflected in the code.

Comment: If the HTML can be changed, then I agree with @Lapskaus

Comment: The markup can be changed and @Lapskaus you are correct that each `<h4>` and child `<p>`'s are logically grouped sections of content so I will consider adding a `section` tag.